# boostrap inline form not styling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a inline form, but its not styling correctly.

Below is the code I am using:

```css
body {
  background-color: #a7cdf2;
}

#map {
  height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <link href="/static/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <form class="inline" action="" method="post" name="search">
    <input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="xxx">
      <datalist id="id_datalist">
        <option value="CLARENVILLE, CA">
    </datalist>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="origin">Origin:</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="origin" list="id_datalist" name="origin" size="40" type="text" value="SHANGHAI, CN">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="speed">Speed (knots):</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="speed" name="speed" size="5" type="text" value="14.0">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how it renders in Chrome:
[image]

Comment: And this is how it renders in Chrome on _my_ computer: https://s3.postimg.org/74iglnz5v/Screen_Shot_2017-07-06_at_10.36.38.png

Comment: there is a identical form-group for Destination that I took out due to Stackoverflow limit on lines of code.

Comment: Could you tell us what you want it to look like?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/gbClm this is how it looks from the Bootstrap documentation

Comment: Its actually <form class="form-inline"..> but still doesnt work.

Comment: I messed around with your code, and as soon as I added a link to boostrap JS and CSS the code worked. Perhaps you should consider using cdn's? https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your boostrap links are incorrect... I played around with your code and replaced the links and it worked fine. It looks like either you have put the downloaded files in the wrong place, or perhaps the example you found wasn't clear. When the src has a value like `/static/css/bootstrap.min.css` it is looking at the files on the server hosting the site. Perhaps you should use CDN links instead?

```
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #a7cdf2;
}

#map {
  height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <form class="inline" action="" method="post" name="search">
    <input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="xxx">
    <datalist id="id_datalist">
        <option value="CLARENVILLE, CA">
    </datalist>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="origin">Origin:</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="origin" list="id_datalist" name="origin" size="40" type="text" value="SHANGHAI, CN">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="speed">Speed (knots):</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="speed" name="speed" size="5" type="text" value="14.0">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```